# Can't find neither UseLog4Net nor FromThisAssembly using Castle.Core

Tags: .net-core, castle

I'm trying to learn more about .Net Core and Castle dependency injection and inversion of control, but I just can't find neither `UseLog4Net` in `LoggingFacility`, while implementing my `CompositionRoot`, nor `FromThisAssembly` in `Classes` while implementing my installers. What am I doing wrong?

**CompositionRoot.cs**

```
using Castle.Facilities.Logging;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace PitchulaBeerNBurger.POS.CrossCuttingConcerns.DependencyInjection
{
    public class CompositionRoot
    {
        public virtual void ComposeApplication(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseLog4Net());

            container.Install(
                new Installers.CrossCuttingConcerns(),
                new Installers.Persistence(),
                new Installers.Domain(),
                new Installers.Business()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**DomainInstaller.css**

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace PitchulaBeerNBurger.POS.CrossCuttingConcerns.Installers
{
    public class Domain : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                                      .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Factory"))
                                      .LifestyleSingleton());
        }
    }
}
```

**NuGet packages installed:**

```
Castle.Core.4.3.1
Castle.Core-log4net.4.3.1
Castle.LoggingFacility
```